# Add value for key in dictionary which is inside the list in python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have to prepare JSON files to send using POST, but I have faced the following format to handle:

```
offer { 
         "location":
         {
         "city": "Kharkov",
         "address": "street"
         }
         "dates": [
         {
            "start_date": "2018-10-10 14:00",
            "end_date": "2018-11-11 14:00"
         }]
}
```

Before it, to set the **Value** for the city field I used the following implementation:

```
offer['location']['city'] = "Kharkov"
```

But now I can't figure out how to add the value to the key **start_date** since the dictionary is inside the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'dates'` is a list. Use index to access the key inside.

**Ex:**

```
offer['dates'][0]["start_date"] = "NewDate"
print(offer)
```

**Output:**

```
{'dates': [{'start_date': 'NewDate', 'end_date': '2018-11-11 14:00'}], 'location': {'city': 'Kharkov', 'address': 'street'}}
```